# Unable to scroll down the web page using the Robot Framework

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I am using Selenium 2 and Robot Framework to automate our application. I have used the below JavaScript code to scroll down the page but am not able to scroll.

I want to enter text inside the text box after scrolling down, but I am receiving the exception:

> Element not visible

The text box is partially visible on the screen by default, if we manually scroll down than its completely visible, But selenium robot framework unable to scroll down.

I have tried:

```
Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0,200)

Execute JavaScript    window.scrollBy(0,200)

Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try selecting the window before trying to scroll in it, selenium.selectWindow("id=theWindowID");

Comment: Try to use the "Focus" keyword!
It help me!

Answer (score 4):

Your scrolling code looks ok. However, I don't think scrolling is your problem. Element visibility is ok even if it is scrolled away from screen. Try this code for example. At least on Chrome page scrolls back up at *Input Text* keyword

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Scroll
    Open Browser   http://www.stackoverflow.com/    Chrome
    Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
    Input Text    //*[@id="search"]/input    robot framework
    Sleep    3
    Close All Browsers
```

I think you may have an incorrect locator for your edit box.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue with `Execute JavaScript ${element}.scrollby(0,200)`. It will not work in every case. If the element is not in a viewport it will not scroll.

There's an efficient way to scroll the page to get the element to a view port.

If we are using `Execute JavaScript     Window.scroll(x,y)`, we need to specify a horizontal and vertical position, x,y, which is difficult to find and may not be accurate.

Instead we can use the following line of code,
`Execute JavaScript    window.document.evaluate("//xpathlocation", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true);`

The above code will scroll the window and get the element specified in /xpathlocation to the view port.

Comment: how can i get a return value of it

Answer (score 1):

Execute JavaScript   window.scrollTo(1,500) works for me with Python2 ; you have just to put x <> 0 for exemple '1' otherwise it wont' scroll

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in Selenium webdriver in the IPython console directly?

I have tried as in the following, and it is able to scroll down.

```
from selenium import webdriver
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get('http://twitter.com')
firefox.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,200)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a keyword:

```
Execute Javascript    $(document).scrollTop(${x})
```

Where,

**x** is the number in milliseconds to scroll down.

Comment: milli**seconds**? It's not milliseconds. You should also mention that `scrollTop()` is a jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

If there is another element inside your page with scroll bar which you want to scroll into, you can use this Execute javascript command:

```
Execute Javascript   document.querySelector('<div.css>').scrollTop = 200;
```

You can just change the '200' and increase it as you want to scroll down more.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following it worked for me

Fill in the required info

```
input text      id:userName         Joe Biden
input text      id:userEmail        Joe@att.net
input text      id:currentAddress   211 Madison Ave NY
execute javascript  window.scrollTo(0,200)
scroll element into view         id:submit
```

you will need to select the window before scrolling

Answer (score 0):

i tried by pressing tab for number of times till I landed to my element..!

```
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${Range}
    Press Keys    NONE    TAB 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

i just ended up by pressing TAB key by required number of times, choose an element and press TAB key

```
Click Element    ${Element}   
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${Range}// you can even provide number 
    Press Keys    NONE    TAB 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below.

```
Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).