# Robot framework - Scroll in DIV tag

Tags: robotframework

I need to scroll in DIV tag. Is there a way to do it? 
Currently I am using **Execute JavaScript** keyword to do that. But it's not working.
Execute JavaScript

```
var sc = document.getElementsByClassName("box-body");   
sc.scrollTop +=2000;
```

Comment: Here is the code snippet i am using currently. Execute JavaScript   var sc = document.getElementsByClassName("box-body"); sc.scrollTop  +=2000;

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of all the elements with said classname. If you only have one element that you need to call the first element of that array `sc[0].scrollTop +=2000;`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59559631/9673383

It might help. :)

If there is another element inside your page with scroll bar which you want to scroll into, you can use this Execute javascript command:

```
Execute Javascript   document.querySelector('<div.css>').scrollTop = 200;
```

You can just change the '200' and increase it as you want to scroll down more.