# Unable to scroll to an element on modal window dialog using robot framework

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I have a modal window which opens on element click. That window has a 'submit' button which isnt visible initially and need to be scrolled to bring it into view. I looked at the 4th answer in this question: [Unable to scroll down the web page using the Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947891/unable-to-scroll-down-the-web-page-using-the-robot-framework)
Which basically says to use below snippet:

```
Execute Javascript    window.document.evaluate("//xpathlocation", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true);
```

However, I am not sure what I need to replace 2nd argument with. Since for now my guess is its trying to look the element on the window and not the modal window. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The part you want to change in your given example, is the `//xpathlocation` string. You should replace this with a XPath to locate your submit button.

Next thing, assuming your modal is a true window, and not an emulated window via javascript (using libraries such as [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/)), you'll want to switch to your modal window, using the keyword [Select Window](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Window). Once you've selected your modal window, the javascript should work fine.