# Scrolling on a page to a locator using Robot Framework

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I have been working with robot framework on a page written in java/java script. I am trying to scroll to a locator to be optically visible on the page to be able to verify its text value. I did follow this QA based on my question and found a solution, however it pops me an exception.

> [Unable to scroll down the web page using the Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947891/unable-to-scroll-down-the-web-page-using-the-robot-framework)

My locator to scroll to on the page:

```
${CLAIMS}    xpath=//*[@id="generalAndIncidents:relatedAlertsPanel:idPreviousClaimsList"]
```

My keyword to do the scrolling (it has one argument for a locator variable to be loaded):

```
Scroll To Element
[Arguments]    ${scroll_to_element}
Sleep    1s
Execute JavaScript    window.document.evaluate("${scroll_to_element}", document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true);
Sleep    1s
```

And when running, I receive the following exception:

```
20:36:17.376    INFO    Executing JavaScript:
window.document.evaluate("xpath=//*[@id="generalAndIncidents:relatedAlertsPanel:idPreviousClaimsList"]", document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true);
Without any arguments.  
20:36:17.758    FAIL    JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=86.0.622.69)
```

I also have checked this page for the "how-to" on this java script code snippet:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Could you kindly suggest me where to start debugging? What am I doing wrong here? Is this happening because I am missing any escapes?

Thank you very much!

**Update#1:** Could this be something to do with the namespace resolver?

**Update#2:**

```
Scroll To Element
    [Arguments]    ${scroll_to_element}
    ${x} =    Get Horizontal Position    ${scroll_to_element}
    ${y} =    Get Vertical Position      ${scroll_to_element}
    Execute Javascript    window.scrollTo(${x}, ${y})

Scroll Loop Click
    [Arguments]    ${locator}
    FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    1    10
        Sleep    0.5s
        ${isElementVisible} =    Run Keyword and Return Status    Click Element    ${locator}
        Run Keyword If    '${isElementVisible}'!='True'    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    6s    2s    Scroll To Element    ${locator}
        Log    ${isElementVisible}
        Exit For Loop If    '${isElementVisible}'=='True'
    END
    Wait Until Element is Visible    ${locator}
```

Comment: Your string uses double quotes, and also contains double quotes. That may be at least part of the problem.

Comment: Hello Bryan, thank you very much. That is likely one of my issues, because when I omit the double quotes I receive the following error:

FAIL InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'xpath://*[@id=generalAndIncidents:relatedAlertsPanel]/div[1]/span' is not a valid XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below code,which is currently working for me. Way back got this solution from Stackoverflow.

```
Scroll To Element
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    ${x}=        Get Horizontal Position  ${locator}
    ${y}=        Get Vertical Position    ${locator}
    Execute Javascript  window.scrollTo(${x}, ${y})
```

Comment: Hi Manish! Thank you very much for the input! It does work! Although my case is a bit specific, because it still will not scroll to the element. Reason is, that it might be already visible, even if it is not optically visible. So I did a loop to check for a click action. But the code you provided is super! I have inserted my function in the first post. :)