# For Firefox Selenium keyword Scroll Element Into View not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, robotframework

I have SPA application in which wanted to scroll down and click on the specific button

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  30 sec  5 sec  SeleniumLibrary.Scroll Element Into View   ${Edit_Btn} 

Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  30 sec  5 sec  SeleniumLibrary.Click Element   ${Edit_Btn}
```

Also, tried Execute Javascript

```
Execute Javascript  document.getElementById("editBtn").click()
```

But it did not work and getting error

```
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: 'SAUCE-WIN10', ip: '10.119.22.184', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode (AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:220)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode (AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute (HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute (DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute (RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute (RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.mouseMove (RemoteMouse.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.internal.EventFiringMouse.mouseMove (EventFiringMouse.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.MouseMoveToLocation.call (MouseMoveToLocation.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.MouseMoveToLocation.call (MouseMoveToLocation.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run (DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (None:-1)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (None:-1)
```

Using firefox version: **98**
OS: **Windows 10**

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

The *JDK* version is old and ancient:

```
java.version: '1.8.0_131'
```

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  latest released version.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer and try once, it will work. It has custom keyword, just pass your locator as argument.

[Scrolling on a page to a locator using Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993726/scrolling-on-a-page-to-a-locator-using-robot-framework/64999907#64999907)